# Using Selenium and XPATH, how would I extract text that follows a bolded link?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract the text using Xclass that follows the bolded politicians name in the below code. I am able to extract the politicians name and URL to their profile, but how would I go about pulling the text that follows?

In the code below, I'm trying to extract it using:

```
desctext = elem.find_element(By.XPATH,".//b/following-sibling::text()")
```

I've tried a million other things, but to no avail. For example on the website it says: "**[Corey Stapleton](https://ballotpedia.org/Corey_Stapleton_presidential_campaign,_2024)** (R), former Montana Secretary of State, announced his candidacy on November 11, 2022.[35] Stapleton withdrew from the race on October 13, 2023"

I want to pull the text after Corey Stapleton. There is an a href tag embedded inside a bold tag and the text follows.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
pres_candidates_url = "https://ballotpedia.org/Presidential_candidates,_2024"
driver.get(pres_candidates_url)
   
elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mw-parser-output']//ul//li")

all_members = []
for elem in elems:
    member = {}
    try:
        linktext = elem.find_element(By.XPATH,".//b//a")
    except:
        continue
    words = linktext.text.split()
    
    print
    # words = elem.text.split()
    
    count = 0
    for w in words: #linktext contains non-names so remove those based on more than one word being lowercase
        if w[0].islower(): 
            count +=1 
    if count < 1:
        name = linktext.text
        member_url = linktext.get_attribute("href")
        try:
            desctext = elem.find_element(By.XPATH,".//b/following-sibling::text()")
        except:
            print("error")
        if "(D)" in desctext:
            party = "Democrat"
        elif "(R)" in desctext:
            party = "Republican"
        else:
            party = desctext
        metadata = {"Party:": party}
        print(name, member_url, metadata)
        member["name"], member["url"], member["metadata"] = name, member_url, metadata 
    else:
        continue
    all_members.append(member)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any choice than to get the parents and parse the text. You can get the parents by doing:

```
parents = elem.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//b/a/../..")
```

This will find all bold anchors/links and go up two levels (so up to <b> and then their parent). You then have to parse their resulting text content.

You can't find it using `following-sibling` because that text is not a sibling element (with a tag of its own)

Comment: Yes, you're a genius Olivier. Thank you so much. This works for what I need perfectly.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler way to do this. I also streamlined the rest of your code.

The XPath below will return the desired elements in one pass.

```
//li[./b/a[@title]]
  ^ return any LI element
     ^ that has a B child
        ^ that has an A child
          ^ that contains a 'title' attribute
```

That returns a list of the filtered LIs that contain the text you want. From there, you can grab the name, URL, and party (I used regex).

The final code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
pres_candidates_url = 'https://ballotpedia.org/Presidential_candidates,_2024'
driver.get(pres_candidates_url)

all_members = []
for elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//li[./b/a[@title]]'):
    member = {}
    member['name'] = elem.find_element(By.XPATH, './b').text
    member['url'] = elem.find_element(By.XPATH, './b/a').get_attribute('href')
    match = re.search(r'\(([\w ]+)\)', elem.text)
    party = ''
    if match:
        party = match.group(1)
    if party == 'R':
        party = 'Republican'
    if party == 'D':
        party = 'Democrat'
    member['party'] = {'Party:': party}
    all_members.append(member)

    print(member['name'], member['url'], member['party'])

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Joe Biden https://ballotpedia.org/Joe_Biden {'Party:': 'Democrat'}
Dean Phillips https://ballotpedia.org/Dean_Phillips {'Party:': 'Democrat'}
Marianne Williamson https://ballotpedia.org/Marianne_Williamson {'Party:': 'Democrat'}
Cenk Uygur https://ballotpedia.org/Cenk_Uygur {'Party:': 'Democrat'}
Ryan Binkley https://ballotpedia.org/Ryan_Binkley {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Doug Burgum https://ballotpedia.org/Doug_Burgum {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Chris Christie https://ballotpedia.org/Chris_Christie_(New_Jersey) {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Ron DeSantis https://ballotpedia.org/Ron_DeSantis_presidential_campaign,_2024 {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Nikki Haley https://ballotpedia.org/Nikki_Haley_presidential_campaign,_2024 {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Asa Hutchinson https://ballotpedia.org/Asa_Hutchinson_presidential_campaign,_2024 {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Vivek Ramaswamy https://ballotpedia.org/Vivek_Ramaswamy_presidential_campaign,_2024 {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Tim Scott https://ballotpedia.org/Tim_Scott_presidential_campaign,_2024 {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Donald Trump https://ballotpedia.org/Donald_Trump_presidential_campaign,_2024 {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Larry Elder https://ballotpedia.org/Larry_Elder_presidential_campaign,_2024 {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Will Hurd https://ballotpedia.org/Will_Hurd_presidential_campaign,_2024 {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Perry Johnson https://ballotpedia.org/Perry_Johnson_presidential_campaign,_2024 {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Mike Pence https://ballotpedia.org/Mike_Pence_presidential_campaign,_2024 {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Corey Stapleton https://ballotpedia.org/Corey_Stapleton_presidential_campaign,_2024 {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Francis Suarez https://ballotpedia.org/Francis_Suarez_presidential_campaign,_2024 {'Party:': 'Republican'}
Robert F. Kennedy Jr. https://ballotpedia.org/Robert_F._Kennedy_Jr. {'Party:': 'Independent'}
Chase Oliver https://ballotpedia.org/Chase_Oliver {'Party:': 'Libertarian Party'}
Cornel West https://ballotpedia.org/Cornel_West {'Party:': 'Independent'}
```